# prevent duplicates in the range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a macro which prevents duplicates within the range A:H

But I don't know how to change the macro so it prevents input of "[name] [space] [surname]" more than twice. There can be a number of "[name] [space] [surname]" in one cell

```
 Option Explicit
 Option Compare Text


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim What As Variant


Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A:H")
If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
What = "*" & Target.Value & "*"
For Each cel In rng.Cells
    If cel.Value Like What Then
        Target.ClearContents
        MsgBox "Text already present!"
    End If
Next cel
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your worksheet? Also, the way you have your code, if a value is changed in `rng.cells`, it will always return a match as you are not ignoring the cell where the value was changed

Comment: I don't know how to paste a snapshot.

Comment: a have numer of names and surnames (separated by " ") in each cell in columns A:H, each pair is spearateted with ", ". macro should prevent me from entering more than 2 pairs in this range (somewhere in the cell)

Comment: If the names in a cell are always separated by ",", can you not just get the count of commas in the cells and base your validation on that?

Comment: I don't know how to do that